# How do I split a vector in half such that the sum of the terms in each half are a minimum?

Tags: matrices, optimization, integer-programming

I've been struggling with this problem for several days now, perhaps because I am approaching it the wrong way.  Hopefully someone can help me see the light!

**PROBLEM**

Consider that there are four cups of pennies.  Each cup has a random amount of pennies.

I need to determine how to split the cups into two groups, two cups in each group, such that the total pennies in one group less the total pennies in the second group is a minimum, and ideally zero.

It is very simple to solve this problem if I knew the amount of pennies in each cup.  So I want to use linear algebra to help me determine those amounts.  Once I have the amounts, I can run trial summations on a fast computer to find an optimum division of the cups.

I cast the problem in the context of four cups.  But the practical application I am trying to solve might have 32 cups, so the number of combinations that would need to be tested is $\binom{32}{16}$, which is over 60 million.  Doing that manually would take forever.

**MATHEMATICAL APPROACH**

Assume $A$ is a vector that represents the unknown number of pennies in each cup, $B$ is a multitude of vectors that assign each cup to a group, and $C$ is the difference in total pennies between the groups of cups.

$$A=C\cdot B^{-1}$$

While I believe I have the problem setup correctly, the determinant of $B$ is always zero given the requirements of $B$.  So I can't determine the number of pennies in each cup.

Conditions;

$$n\in\{2\cdot\mathbb{Z}\}\mid n\geqslant2\
$$

$$A=[\left|a_1\right|... \left|a_n\right|]$$

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
           c_{1}\\
           \vdots \\
           c_{n}\\
         \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
           B_{x}\\
           B_{y}\\
         \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B_x=\begin{bmatrix}
           b_{1,1} \dots b_{n,1} \\
           \vdots \\
           b_{1,\frac{n}{2}} \dots b_{n,\frac{n}{2}} \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B_{y}=-B_x$$

with the further limitation that all terms in $B_x$ are arbitrarily assigned either +1 or -1, and each column vector in $B_x$ is unique.

By assigning $B_y$ = -$B_x$ ,each column of $B$ is guaranteed to have one set of $\frac{n}{2}$ terms = 1 and another equal size set of $\frac{n}{2}$ terms = -1.

Given that all terms in $A$ are positive, the balanced column vectors of $B$ effectively separates the $A$ vector into two equal length vectors; a positive vector group and negative vector group.  The ultimate goal is to find a column vector, not necessarily in $B$, that creates a minimum summation of all terms in $A$.  But if the determinant of $B$ is always zero, I don't see how to solve my problem.  Am I making a mistake or is there a better way to approach the problem?

Any thoughts?

Comment: In the second paragraph, you introduce randomness, but then you never refer to it again; the problem doesn't seem to be a probabilistic one. Perhaps you mean "arbitrary" where it says "random"?

Comment: In the context of the problem, isn't arbitrary the same as random?  There are 2^n/2 possible column vectors, but only have n defined.

Comment: No. "arbitrary" means it can be any number, and the solution should work for any number, but in any given instance of the problem the number is fixed. "random" means that the number is a random variable following some distribution, and it makes sense e.g. to ask for its expected value, its variance, the probability of it taking certain values, etc. You didn't introduce a distribution, and you don't ask for any such probabilistic quantities.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the [*subset sum problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete.  You can solve it via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $n_i$ be the number of pennies in cup $i$.  Let binary variable $x_i$ indicate whether the pennies in cup $i$ are assigned to group A.  The rest will be assigned to group B.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to:
\begin{align}
z &\ge \sum_i n_i x_i \\
z &\ge \sum_i n_i (1-x_i) \\
\sum_i x_i &= 16
\end{align}
This formulation is a linear way to minimize the maximum number of pennies in the two groups.  Because the total number of pennies is constant, minimizing the maximum is equivalent to minimizing the difference.

If the $n_i$ are not distinct, with frequencies $f_i$, you can instead replace the binary variables with (fewer) nonnegative integer variables $x_i$ that represent the number of times that $n_i$ appears in group A.  The new linear constraints are:
\begin{align}
z &\ge \sum_i n_i x_i \\
z &\ge \sum_i n_i (f_i-x_i) \\
\sum_i x_i &= 16 \\
0 \le x_i &\le f_i 
\end{align}
This both reduces the problem size and helps eliminate symmetry.  For the problem data provided, there are 15 distinct frequencies, and an optimal solution looks like this:
$$
\begin{matrix}
i &n_i &f_i &x_i\\ 
\hline
1 &968 &1 &1 \\
2 &972 &1 &1 \\
3 &984 &4 &0 \\
4 &988 &3 &3 \\
5 &992 &3 &3 \\
6 &996 &2 &1 \\
7 &1000 &1 &1 \\
8 &1004 &5 &1 \\
9 &1008 &1 &1 \\
10 &1012 &4 &0 \\
11 &1016 &2 &0 \\
12 &1020 &1 &0 \\
13 &1032 &2 &2 \\
14 &1044 &1 &1 \\
15 &1052 &1 &1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: If I have 60 million possible combinations, are you saying I should perform 60 million tests?  Tests take milliseconds.  Computers calculate in nanoseconds.

Comment: No, you should use an integer linear programming solver, which implicitly searches all possibilities, typically much faster than brute force.  If you supply some test data, I'll illustrate.

Comment: When you write "typically", does that mean not always?

Comment: There are pathological cases that that require complete enumeration, but almost always, ILP outperforms brute force.

Comment: Rob, is there an easy way to submit some test data in a form that you can use directly?

Comment: Just list the 32 numbers of pennies.

Comment: 1004 984 1008 1032 1016 1012 984 1012 984 988 992 1004 992 1000 1012 972 1004 1052 1044 1004 1012 968 1004 996 1016 984 1032 988 1020 996 992 988

Comment: Solves instantly, with 16048 in each group.. Group A is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,18,22,24,26,27,31\}$.

Comment: What is the B vector?  And what does instantly mean in the context that the hardware platform where this has to run does not support a solver?

Comment: Group B is the complement: $\{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,20,21,23,25,28,29,30,32\}$.  Not sure what you mean by B vector.  Instantly is 0.06 seconds on my laptop, using an ILP solver.  I don't know how you will solve this on your hardware.

Comment: I got the B vector and checks out. 1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
1
-1
-1
-1
1
-1
1
-1
1
1
-1
-1
-1
1
-1  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer.

Comment: Rob, you wrote: "If the () are not distinct, ...". In the case of my problem--unknown n(i)--I have no way to know f(i). I only know z and x. Did the solution approach you suggested start with known values for n(i)?  

Apparently, the problem I want to solve is a specialized case of the subset sum problem.  http://www.zrzahid.com/equal-partitioning-with-minimum-difference-in-sum/

Comment: The second formulation is just a generalization.  If $f_i=1$ for all $i$, you get the first formulation as a special case.  I'm not sure what you mean by unknown $n_i$; they are part of the input, and you can compute $f_i$ from that, before solving the optimization problem.

Comment: As I wrote in the original question, I have no idea how many pennies are in a cup (i.e. the n[i] in your answer).  All I know are the digital vectors for testing a case, and the result of that test.  The question was how do I determine the pennies in each cup.  Or said another way, how do I solve the equation given that the B determinant always equals zero.

Comment: So the problem has two steps.  Determine the amount of pennies in each cup, and then determine how to partition the cups.  Ideally, I want to bypass the first problem (how many pennies in a cup) and go straight to the solution--the optimum binary vector.  I don't really care (or have a way to see) how many pennies are in a cup.  I just want to know how to partition them.

Comment: I see.  My answer addresses only the second step, which is already a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presenting a quadratic binary optimization apporach:

Let $x_i=1$ if object $i$ belongs to group $1$ and $x_i=-1$ if it belongs to group $2$.

Let the value be $v_i$.

Hence, we want to minimize $$\min_i \left(\sum_iv_ix_i\right)^2=\sum_i v_i^2 +\sum_{i<j}2v_iv_jx_ix_j$$

subject to $$\sum_i x_i=0$$

$$x_i \in \{1,-1\}$$

If you have access to a QUBO(quadratic unconstrained programming optimization) solver. To convert it to an unconstrained problem, we want to solve

$$\min_i  \sum_i v_i^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}2v_iv_jx_ix_j + A\sum_i x_i$$

where $A$ is a parameter that we have to tune to make sure that the constraint is satisfied and to convert the variable to binary, just use the transformation $y_i = \frac{x_i+1}2$.

Remark: While  we can theoretically derived a large value for $A$ that is equivalent to the original problem, a large value might not be suitable when it comes to real life solver. I might want to first set it to a large value then reduce it slowly.

Also, on this [page](http://www.zrzahid.com/equal-partitioning-with-minimum-difference-in-sum/), a heuristic with $O(n^2)$ time complexity and $O(n)$ space complexity is proposed to obtain a feasible solution.

Comment: Given the two answers so far, including yours, it seems that the problem I want to solve is not so simple.  I don't have an option to use math solvers on the hardware platform where this must run.  Do you think I can use a neural network to more rapidly solve the problem since I don't need an exact solution?

Comment: try the heuristic in the link? There is this paper "Performance of a neural network method with set partitioning" but I have not read it in details yet.